# Change and refresh icons programmatically (without rebooting)

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, windows-xp

When I'm replacing icons manually (i.e. NOT from the Folder Options window in explorer), the icon(s) aren't being updated. For example, if I execute this batch code:

```
REG ADD HKCR\testfile\DefaultIcon /ve /d "C:\test.ico,0" /f
```

the icon(s) show like they should in the list in Folder Options, but the icons aren't updated on the desktop or in explorer.

The icons are updated if I just hit the "change icon" button for any file type and exit the Folder Options window. But this can't be done via batch or VBS as far as I know.

Restarting explorer.exe DOES work, but if I do that, the application tabs in the task bar become buggy for some reason (e.g.: when an application is maximized, I can't just left click the tab in the task bar to minimize it anymore - I have to actually right click it and hit minimize...). Not to mention, if I do it that way, all open explorer windows will close down, and that's a little bothersome.

I also have a copy of **TuneUp Utilities**, which has an option for reloading the icon cache, and this does work like intended. But once again, I can't access this tool via batch or VBS. And it doesn't restart explorer.exe or remove any files (like some solutions do). I'm positive of this since I don't have iconcache.db files **anywhere** on my OS drive.

I also tried adding the registry entries via VBS instead, but that didn't help.

Any batch or VBScript solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By associating files, the system refreshes the icons, so my simple solution was just this:

```
ASSOC .anyextension=anytype
ASSOC .anyextension=
```

Second row disassociates the extension.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=42394&lngWId=1) has a VB program that rebuilds the cache (look at **frmRebuiltIconCache.frm** for the actual code)

What it does is to examine the value of `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\Shell Icon Size`, subtract 1 from it, forces a timeout via `SendMessageTimeout`, then resets the value, and repeats the timeout

due to the fact you cannot call a DLL from vbs (without an external program), this may not give you what you need. I have pared down the program to this:

```
'SendMessageTimeout values
Const HWND_BROADCAST = &HFFFF
Const WM_SETTINGCHANGE = &H1A
Const SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS = &H2A
Const SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = &H2

'Private Declare Function SendMessageTimeout Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageTimeoutA" _
'  (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal msg As Long, _
'  ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long, _
'  ByVal fuFlags As Long, ByVal uTimeout As Long, _
'  lpdwResult As Long) As Long

Dim icon_size
Dim new_icon_size
Dim result
Dim SysVarReg
Set SysVarReg = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    ' Get the current icon size.
icon_size = SysVarReg.RegRead ("HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\Shell Icon Size")
    ' Increase the value by 1.
new_icon_size = CInt(icon_size) + 1
SysVarReg.RegWrite "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\Shell Icon Size", new_icon_size
    ' Send HWND_BROADCAST to refresh the icons.
SendMessageTimeout HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 10000, result
    ' Restore the original value.
SysVarReg.RegWrite "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\Shell Icon Size", icon_size
    ' Send HWND_BROADCAST to refresh the icons again.
SendMessageTimeout HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 10000, result
```

but without something to wrap the DLL call in, you will be unable to do this via vbs

Comment: This is not a VB**Script** solution. There isn't a way to port it to VBS either, is there? The reason why I need it to be batch or VBS, is because this should be executed directly after re-installing the OS. So I shouldn't have to install other programs first. Thanks though!

Comment: I get this error when I try it: Syntax error, Line 1, Char 9, Code 800A03EA. I don't know if it works any different on other Windows systems, but it doesn't work for me in XP at least...

Answer (score 0):

```
' It work in XP.

' The following is "VBA" Module.

' ---------------------------------------------------------

'SendMessageTimeout values
Const HWND_BROADCAST = &HFFFF
Const WM_SETTINGCHANGE = &H1A
Const SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS = &H2A
Const SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = &H2

Private Declare Function SendMessageTimeout Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageTimeoutA" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal msg As Long, _
  ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long, _
  ByVal fuFlags As Long, ByVal uTimeout As Long, _
  lpdwResult As Long) As Long


Sub Rebuild_Icon_cache()

Dim icon_size
Dim new_icon_size
Dim result
Dim SysVarReg

Set SysVarReg = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Get the current icon size.
icon_size = SysVarReg.RegRead("HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\Shell Icon Size")

' Increase the value by 1.
new_icon_size = CInt(icon_size) + 1
SysVarReg.RegWrite "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\Shell Icon Size", new_icon_size

' Send HWND_BROADCAST to refresh the icons.
SendMessageTimeout HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 10000, result

' Restore the original value.
SysVarReg.RegWrite "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\Shell Icon Size", icon_size

' Send HWND_BROADCAST to refresh the icons again.
SendMessageTimeout HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 10000, result

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you add some additional information, along with your answer?

Comment: Sloppy. `dim result`? ERROR: Additional information: A call to PInvoke function 'WHoSeBox!WHoSeBox.MainBoot::SendMessageTimeout' has unbalanced the stack.