# How does "Sysinternals Autoruns" refreshes desktop icons on windows 8.1?

Tags: icons, refresh, windows-8.1, sysinternals

I've been trying to refresh desktop icons in windows 8.1 without rebooting or closing session and it would seem that "Sysinternals Autoruns" when run will refresh desktop icons. How should I proceed to find what it is doing so I can use the method in my code ?

Comment: what do you mean with "refreshes desktop icons"?

Comment: I mean that if there are some shortcut that are white because the target executable was not available, there must be a way to refresh the icons so that the when the executable become available the white icon is changed to the correct icon.

Comment: I ended up using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263577/change-and-refresh-icons-programmatically-without-rebooting/13283187#13283187

Comment: ok, post your way as answer and accept it.