# Powershell desktop refresh

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Trying to make it where powershell minimizes all windows, refreshes the desktop, then brings it back up. Thing is.. the desktop doesn't refresh after the windows minimize.

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$shell.minimizeall()
start-sleep 1
$shell.sendkeys('{F5}')
start-sleep 1
$shell.undominimizeall()
exit
```

Comment: `Shell.Application` doesn't have a method called `Sendkeys`.  You're thinking of `WScript.Shell`.

Comment: i don't know the answer ... but i do wonder - why are you specifying so many PoSh versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$shell.minimizeall()
start-sleep 1
$wsh = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wsh.sendkeys('{F5}')
start-sleep 1
$shell.undominimizeall()
exit
```

Comment: That did not work for but this did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263577/change-and-refresh-icons-programmatically-without-rebooting/13283187#13283187